# Heroku logs show sql error after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Making good progress on rails now, but hit a snag on heroku deployment. After committing to git and then doing git push heroku master, I've gotten an error twice in the heroku logs when I try and open /users/sign_up

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 12.123.234.345 at Mon Sep 20 14:39:05 -0700 2010
  Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
Completed   in 3ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
):
```

What's annoying me is some combination of restarting the app server on heroku, and doing heroku db:reset fixed it the first time, but I cannot now replicate what it was that fixed it. The error above sounds like it hasn't migrated the users table properly.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Just some extra data,  typing heroku console User.count ... causes the same error. The question is what's going wrong?

Comment: And running heroku db:push solves it, but does not explain why it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database on Heroku was probably empty. Did you migrate the database on Heroku after you deployed? If not it's just an empty database.

`db:push` solved your problem because you pushed your development database over top of the empty one, so it started working.

Comment: I had this same problem. What you could have done instead was `heroku rake db:migrate` to run your migrations on the Heroku database and create a fresh db there. This page helped me: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart